# Why filters are trained differently based on the same image in CNN Deep Learning?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm a beginner in CNN DeepLearning, I know the basic concept that we use some filters to generate a set of feature maps from an image, we activate it using non-linear method like 'relu' before we downsample it. We keep doing this until the image becomes very small. Then we flatten it and use a fully connected network to calculate its category. And we use the back-propergation technique to calculate all parameters in the map. One thing I don't understand is that when we do Conv2D we create many filters(channels) from an image. Like in the sample code:

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
```

I understand this is to generate as many features as possible. But how these filters are trained to detect different features from one image? If all of them are initialized with the same value (like 0) then they should end up with detecting the same feature, right? Are we giving them random values during initialization so that they can find their local minimum loss using gradient descent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initialize all filters with the same value, then you are right, they will learn the same thing. That's why we never initialize with same value. We initialize each kernel with random values (usually 0 mean and some small variance).

There are many methods to find out a good initialization for your network. One of the most famous and used ones is *Xavier initialization*.

Comment: @stoneyan, if my answer helped you please consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what being discussed, the weights in the CONV layer also learns the same way weights learn in FC layer, through backpropagation, using some optimization algorithm (GD, Adam, RMSprop etc). Ending up in local optimum is very unlikely in big networks as a point being local optimum for all the weights is very unlikely as no of weights increases. If weights are initialized with zeros, the gradients become the same for the update and hidden units become the same in a layer. Hence they learn the same features. Hence we use random initialization with mean 0 and variance inversely proportional to the number of units in the previous layer. (eg Xavier)

Comment: Ending up in a local optimum is not unlikely, and in fact most of the time we end up in a local minimum. What's unlikely is to end up in a Global optimum, which, however, we don't usually try to do, as local minimums usually give us similar results as global minimum would. Furthermore, seeking global minimum can lead to overfitting.